# Problem with Mercurial hg serve command

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When using the `hg serve` command in windows, the server starts correctly, but when somebody tries to do a clone, this error appears.

```
$ hg serve
listening at http://machineX:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 4456)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 558, in process_request_thread
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 320, in finish_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 42, in __init__
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 615, in __init__
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 329, in handle
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 323, in handle_one_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 74, in do_GET
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 65, in do_POST
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 58, in do_write
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 122, in do_hgweb
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 85, in __call__
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 117, in run_wsgi
ErrorResponse
----------------------------------------
```

It seems this is some sort of python error... I've already tried reinstalling to the lastest version of mercurial, but still the same problem occurs.

anybody else seen this before?

thanks!

Comment: Which version of mercurial do you use? Does this error also occur when you serve from an empty (=just created) repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It a dumb problem...

I was doing `hg serve` on my "hello" repository, and I was trying to access it as

`hg clone http://machine:8000/hello`

you shouldn't use the repo name in the address...

that is all.

Comment: Thanks for writing this... I got the same error, and probably for the same reason. What a horribly un-diagnostic error message. Somebody needs to teach that python programmer how to write "path not found". It's all the worse because this problem is most likely to happen to new Hg users, and discourage them from using Hg.